# Append database prefix to table name with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm wondering if there is a way to have Sequelize append the database name to a specific query.

When Sequelize runs a query it looks like this:

```
SELECT "desired_field" FROM "user_account" AS "user_account" WHERE "user_account"."username" = 'jacstrong' LIMIT 1;
```

And it returns nothing.

However when I run a manual query from the command line it returns the data I want.

```
SELECT "desired_field" FROM database_name."user_account" AS "user_account" WHERE "user_account"."username" = 'jacstrong' LIMIT 1;
```

Is there any way to make Sequelize do this?

Note: Everything is running fine in my production environment, but I exported the production db and ran pg_restore on my local machine and the application isn't connecting to it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i do this all the time.... before you do the backup make sure you tick the Dump Options --> Do Not Save --> Owner to yes.... Sometimes mine still looks like it fails but really it doesn't... i also don't bother dropping the whole database all the time, i just drop the schema i am restoring... so in reality you could just go ahead and create your database locally with whatever credentials your dev environment is using and just drop the desired schema/schemas and restore the db with no owner when you wanna blow your data away